# Why I'm not able to trigger the "change" event here?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I'm [testing](https://jsfiddle.net/fj7a1v0s/1/) the jQuery Knob Plugin:

```
$(function() {
  $(".knob").knob({
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
    'change': function (value) {
      $('#display').html("some process: " + value);
    }
  });

  $('#random').click(function() {
    $(".knob").val(Math.random() * 100).trigger('change');
  });
});
```

I I drag the knob manually (with mouse), it correctly "trigger" the change function, and change the correct value.

But if I trigger it manually (i.e. `.trigger()`, after a click) it just change the value of the knob: it doesn't trigger the binded "change "event.

Why? How can I fix it?

On [manual](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob#set-the-value) it seems I can do it.

Comment: You mean like clicking on the Random button it's not triggering the change?

Comment: @Keith yes, it should trigger the change method inside knob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "change" to "release".

```
$(function() {
  $(".knob").knob({
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
    "release": function (value) {
       $('#display').html("some process: " + value);
    }
  });

  $('.knob').trigger(
  'configure',
   {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,

  })

  $('#random').click(function() {
    $(".knob").val(Math.random() * 100).change();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/an3r8fos/